# Object extraction from Images with python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, cbir

I want to object extraction from Images. for example i want to count of human in a picture or find similar picture in great data base(like google example) or finding field of picture (Nature of Office or Home) and etc.

did you know any python library or module for do this work. 
If you can link me

- tutrial or instruction to this work
- similar example project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using [simplecv](http://simplecv.org/)?

Here is [a video](http://pyvideo.org/video/1796/simplecv-computer-vision-using-python) of a presenter at pycon who runs through a quick tutorial of how to use simplecv. About half-way through, at 9:50, she demonstrates how to detect faces in an image, which you might be able to use for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out: https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose

I used it to detect multiple persons and extract the skeleton joints. It's also a little sensitive, so post-processing needs to be done to remove outliers caused due to reflections on the floor, glass walls, etc.